# JS Ternary operator confusion

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, ternary

I'm learning about ternary operators now. I got the basics down, but then I saw this snippet and it doesn't make any sense to me. Can anyone please explain how is it put together?!

```
b.m & 4 || (c |= 2, 63 <= a && 77 >= a ? a = 65 : 48 <= a && 57 >= a ? a = 48 : c & 1 ? 97 <= a && 122 >= a ? a = 65 : 197 == a || 229 == a ? c &= 5 : 192 <= a && 687 >= a ? a = 192 : 1536 <= a ? a = 1536 : 912 <= a ? a = 912 : 160 <= a ? a = 160 : 127 <= a ? c &= 5 : 33 <= a ? a = 59 : c &= 5 : 48 > a ? c &= 5 : 65 > a ? a = 59 : 96 > a ? c &= 5 : 112 > a ? a = 96 : 187 > a ? c &= 5 : a = 59);
```

**b.m & 4 ||** are bit operations as far as I understood, then **(c |= 2,** another bit operation, but what does comma mean?!

Then there's 
63 <= a && 77 >= a ? a = 65 : 48

which translates to

> if(a >= 63 && a <= 77){
>   a = 65
>   } else {
>   a = 48;
>   }

and then after that comes **<= a && 57 >= a ? a = 48 : c & 1 ? 97 <= a** which doesn't make any sense to me at all. because 48 was for the previous statement. Can anyone

Comment: man that's a long operation. headache just looking at it. all I can help you with is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comma is a separate [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in javascript:

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the second operand.

You have grasped just a part of expression:

> Then there's 63 <= a && 77 >= a ? a = 65 : 48

Actually it is a little bit longer (with some formatting):

```
63 <= a && 77 >= a
    ? a = 65
    : 48 <= a && 57 >= a
        ? a = 48
        : c & 1
            ? 97 <= a && 122 >= a
                ? a = 65
                : 197 == a || 229 == a
                    ? c &= 5
                    : 192 <= a && 687 >= a
                        ? a = 192
                        : 1536 <= a
                            ? a = 1536
                            : 912 <= a
                                ? a = 912
                                : 160 <= a
                                    ? a = 160
                                    : 127 <= a
                                        ? c &= 5
                                        : 33 <= a
                                            ? a = 59
                                            : c &= 5
            : 48 > a
                ? c &= 5
                : 65 > a
                    ? a = 59
                    : 96 > a
                        ? c &= 5
                        : 112 > a
                            ? a = 96
                            : 187 > a
                                ? c &= 5
                                : a = 59
```

Trying to rewrite it in if-else fasion will yield the following result:

```
if (63 <= a && 77 >= a){
    a = 65
} else if (48 <= a && 57 >= a){
    a = 48
} else if (c & 1){
    if (97 <= a && 122 >= a){
        a = 65
    } else if (197 == a || 229 == a){
        c &= 5
    } else if (192 <= a && 687 >= a){
        a = 192
    } else if (1536 <= a){
        a = 1536
    } else if (912 <= a){
        a = 912
    } else if (160 <= a){
        a = 160
    } else if (127 <= a){
        c &= 5
    } else if (33 <= a){
        a = 59
    } else {
        c &= 5
    }               
} else {
    if (48 > a){
        c &= 5
    } else if (65 > a){
        a = 59
    } else if (96 > a){
        c &= 5
    } else if (112 > a){
        a = 96
    } else if (187 > a){
        c &= 5
    } else {
        a = 59
    }
}
```

Please, **pay attention** that if-else approach lacks returning value currently, whereas ternary operator does return the value of the last operator executed (this may affect the overall value of boolean expression in parentheses).

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yeah i was just trying to understand the beginning, but now it's much easier to understand, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to format nested ternary statements [like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6544/ternary-operation-java-isnt-this-abuse/6562#6562), so they have a simple, readable structure:

```
//   (is this true) ? then do this  
//   (is this true) ? then do this  
// (all else fails) : then do this
```

Following that structure, it would look something like this:

```
  63 <= a && 77 >= a ? a = 65
: 48 <= a && 57 >= a ? a = 48
:              c & 1 ? /* then go into this indented block below */
                         97 <= a && 122 >= a ? a = 65
:                       197 == a || 229 == a ? c &= 5
:                       192 <= a && 687 >= a ? a = 192
:                                  1536 <= a ? a = 1536
:                                   912 <= a ? a = 912
:                                   160 <= a ? a = 160
:                                   127 <= a ? c &= 5
:                                    33 <= a ? a = 59
                                  /* else */ : c &= 5
:            48 > a ? c &= 5
:            65 > a ? a = 59
:            96 > a ? c &= 5
:           112 > a ? a = 96
:           187 > a ? c &= 5
   /* final else */ : a = 59
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma isn't a ternary operator, it allows two expressions to replace one.

But more importantly, that's a mess.  Break it down, format it, and comment it.  Unless you're golfing, combining all of that into one pile is just abusive.